# How to get short access token for Facebook dynamically

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to build kinda bot to post automatically some links from my database ( of my blog ) on my page.

On the documentation to get the page access token I have to get first the **short token** then the **long one** and finally the **page token**

The problem is I have to get the short token from some dashboard on Facebook, not a request I can translate it into code!

I need the whole process to be dynamic not involving me every 60 days to copy the short token into the code over and over which is not making sense.

I hope there a way to get the short token better than this, as well I need a way to verify the page token if its expired. to let me bot generate a new one automatically!

Comment: Why would you need to get a new short one every 60 days? And the only way to get a user access token is for you to do something. Either copy it from the dashboard or use Facebook Login. There is no way to automatically get one.

Comment: Sorry I have miss understood the documentation, the documentation said that ***long token*** will be valid for only ***60 days***, So I thought the same will be for the ***page token***, But I was wrong as it least forever if I signed with the ***long one***

Comment: There a lot of tokens here, so I got kinda confused, lol.